# How to create professional controls like youtube?

Tags: html, python-2.7, django-templates

I'm working on a HTML and would like to receive controls like youtube.
This is the main problem :

```html
<video width="500" height="50" controls="controls">
     <source src="{{ song.audio_file.url }}">
 </video>
```

I want to receive 'controls' like youtube or something in this style and
not the default one that you recieve -
[default like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36U3t.png)

how can I get this controls? -
[like this controls:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HzcZ.png)

Comment: Is it a video or audio file?

Comment: it is audio.....

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio width="500" height="50" controls>
     <source src="{{ song.audio_file.url }}">
</audio>
```

I presume you need to use the audio tag for this to work.

Comment: right. but i have the same problem, i want to get the style of "YouTube" do you know how can i get it"?

Comment: and for the truth, there is a difference between the browsers(Chrome,Microsoft Edge) in terms of the display... i want this to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  <audio controls preload="auto">
        <source src="song.audio_file.url" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
```

For chrome

```
<iframe src="song.audio_file.url"  width="500" height="50" allow="autoplay">
</iframe>
```

I don't know which file format you are using. If you face problem with a mp3 file then try to converted the *.mp3 file to *.ogg format `<source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">`and add as a second source. Also, sometimes mp3 format with 192kbps doesn't work so try 128 kbps.

Comment: please share more information regarding your requirement.

Comment: so i want to get control on the volume and want more features that you not recieve in the default one, hence, i want another one like Youtube.... clear enough?